# Foreign Key with Fluent Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, fluent

I have created a News Model. My News have an author which is of the Member Class. 
 is this enough for the foreing key to be set?

```
 HasRequired(n => n.Author);
```

Code:

```
public class Member : Identity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<News> News { get; set; }

}

public class News
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtile { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }


    public virtual Member Author;

}
public class NewsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<News>
{
    public NewsMap()
    {

        HasKey(n => n.Id);
        Property(n => n.Id).
            HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .HasColumnName("Id");

        Property(t => t.Title)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100)
            .IsUnicode();
        Property(t => t.Subtile)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100)
            .IsUnicode();
        Property(t => t.Url)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .IsUnicode();
        Property(t => t.DateAdded).HasColumnName("DateAdded")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);

        HasRequired(n => n.Author); //is this enough for the foreing key to be set?



    }

}
public class MemberMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Member>
{
    public MemberMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.FirstName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150);

        this.Property(t => t.LastName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.Email)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150);

        this.Property(t => t.Address.Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100)
            .HasColumnName("Address_FirstLine");

        this.Property(t => t.Address.ZipCode)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(20).HasColumnName("Address_Zip");

        this.Property(t => t.Address.Contry)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnName("Address_Contry");

        this.Property(t => t.Address.City)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnName("Address_Town");

        this.Property(t => t.Id);


        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Identities_Member");
        this.Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
        this.Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");
        this.Property(t => t.Email).HasColumnName("Email");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");

        // Relationships



    }
}
```

Comment: It is not enough. It is too much. Well, strictly speaking. The FK will even be set (as in generated in the database's data model) without the `HasRequired`. With it, the FK will be not nullable.

Comment: Bonus question, saves me from creating another topic. I have Hierarchy by Type. In my database the Identity entry already exists, i now want to add a member(derived class of Identity). I tried to use context.members.AddorUpdate(new Member { id = <a id of existing identity>}). I get a validation failed for one or more entities.

Comment: You should create another topic and show the complete configuration of Member and the internal exception message.

Comment: I remodelled as i could not find a solution. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@Gert for the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622914/foreign-key-with-fluent-entity-framework/12680096#comment17021426_12622914):

> It is not enough. It is too much. Well, strictly speaking. The FK will even be set (as in generated in the database's data model) without the `HasRequired`. With it, the FK will be not nullable.